# Laravel CRUD, Edit and Delete ID Not Found, But ID Exist

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-5.7

Here is migration.

```
Schema::create('ruanganjns', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('kode_jenis_ruangan');
            $table->string('jenis_ruangan');
            $table->date('tgl_berlaku');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here is model.

```
protected $table = 'ruanganjns';
    protected $fillable = ['kode_jenis_ruangan','jenis_ruangan','tgl_berlaku','status'];
    public $timestamps = true;
    public function Ruangan()
    {
        return $this->HasMany('App\Ruangan','id_ruangan');
    }
```

here is controller edit code.

```
public function edit(Ruanganjns $ruanganjns)
    {
        $ruanganjns = Ruanganjns::findOrFail($ruanganjns->id);
        return view('ruanganjns.edit', compact('ruanganjns'));
    }
```

here is the route.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UsOD.png)

The main error always comes from an ID not found. even though all of my code is copied and pasted from the first code source, but the first source code all goes well. and the third source code and so on goes well. the source of the problem is always in this second table even i change it name or make it from beginning it's always the same. are there misspellings or case sensitive or something wrong with my code?

this is the result in the web browser
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGlpb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are trying to implement [Implicit model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#implicit-binding) but you have some wrong variable name in controller action. It should match with the route placeholder like this

Your route is like this

```
Route::get('admin/ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit');
```

Then your controller action code should be like this

```
public function edit(Ruanganjns $ruangjn)  //here $ruangjn should match with route placeholder
{
    return view('ruanganjns.edit', compact('ruangjn'));
}
```

It automatically fetch model record and if record not found then it will return 404 error. For details check the above link