# Laravel edit route not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

Here route code :

```
Route::resource('ruangjns', 'RuanganjnsController');
Route::get('ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit');
```

Here controller :

```
public function edit(Ruanganjns $ruangjn)
    {
        $ruangjn = Ruanganjns::findOrFail($ruangjn->id);
        return view('ruanganjns.edit', compact('ruangjn'));
    }
```

Here view index :

```
<tbody>
@php
$no = 1;
@endphp
@foreach ($ruanganjns as $data)
<tr>
<td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
<td>{{ $data->kode_jenis_ruangan }}</td>
<td>{{ $data->jenis_ruangan }}</td>
<td>{{ $data->tgl_berlaku }}</td>
<td>{{ $data->status }}</td>
<td>
<a href="{{ route('ruangjns.edit', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
</td>
<td>
<form action="{{ route('ruangjns.destroy', $data->id) }}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="return confirm('Are You Absolutely Sure You Want to Delete the Data?')">Delete</button>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Here result form browser

[image]

Lately before i got error code from edit. [This My Post Before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472586/laravel-crud-edit-and-delete-id-not-found-but-id-exist) So i put this code

```
Route::get('ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit');
```

after that work now error going to index can't read an EDIT button like in the picture. But when i search error on browser it have to replace with **URL**

```
<a href="{{ route('ruangjns.edit', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>

<a href="{{ url('ruangjns.edit', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
```

but the main problem is how to access edit if i using **URL** or not using it ?

Thank You.

Comment: if you want to use `url` use it like this :  `url( 'ruangjns/'.{{ $data->id }}.'/edit')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use route inside your view, you should give the route a name, like so:

```
Route::get('ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit')->name('ruangjn-edit');
```

Then just use

```
{{route('ruangjn-edit', ['ruangjn' => $data->id])}}
```

For more information look at the Laravel Routing Documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: No problem mate :)!

Answer (score 3):

Just delete 'Route::get('ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit');'

Laravel Resource controller already has '**edit**' action.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: i once used it before, but still got error. look at my post before.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have not specified any name for the routes.

```
Route::resource('ruangjns', 'RuanganjnsController');
Route::get('ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit')->name('ruangjns.edit');
```

Or the more decent way you can try

```
<a href="{{ url('ruangjns.update', $data->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
```

Moreover only one route  `Route::resource('ruangjns', 'RuanganjnsController');` will do the trick you dont have to specify the separate route because it will be handled by the resource it self.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<a href="{{ route('ruangjns/'.$data->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>

public function edit($ruangjn)
{
    $ruangjn = Ruanganjns::findOrFail($ruangjn);
    return view('ruanganjns.edit', compact('ruangjn'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#urls-for-named-routes), you need write parameters with brackets.
Can you please try with this syntax on the link in your view ?

```
{{ route('ruangjns.edit', ['ruangjns' => $data->id]) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you use described solution bellow, try to use default route - remove your edit route line.
In case you made controller with artisan console command passing flag `-r` to be resourceful, you already have edit method defined. What you do here is overriding default edit method ([check table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers)) writing new edit method that has no route name defined. 
Solutions are to use default method or to use set custom edit method, but importantly, before resource routes.

```
Route::get('ruangjns/{ruangjn}/edit', 'RuanganjnsController@edit')->name('ruangjns.custom-edit');
Route::resource('ruangjns', 'RuanganjnsController');
```

which you would call with {{ $route('ruangjns.custom-edit', $ruangjnsId) }}